# What is going on in my laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, nvidia, graphics

I have a laptop with two gpus (Intel HD4600, Nvidia GTX850M) that's running Ubuntu together with Windows 10 (has no issues) using GRUB.

I have installed `nvidia-355` and i have not installed `bumblebee` due to bad experiences (never got it working/it or me broke the install).

### Problem:

Something display/graphics-related crashes when i have heavy graphical load, and i see a part of the boot messages flash by briefly, and i'm at the login screen again.

#### lscpi output listing both gpus

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
```

#### dmesg output

```
[ 3266.232929] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-d1657723-9e43-04db-5cdc-6df0c522eb41
[ 3266.232946] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception on GPC 0: 3D-C MEMLAYOUT Violation. Coordinates: (0xe0, 0x0)
[ 3266.232954] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 13, Graphics Exception: ESR 0x500420=0x80000400 0x500434=0xe0 0x500438=0x3d00 0x50043c=0x310000
```

This is repeated over and over for a hundred times.

I messed around with my `xorg.conf` this weekend, it looked like this before:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Anything i tried to change was overwritten on the next boot or graphical login.

I added `nogpumanager` to my boot options and got Nvidia X Server Settings to generate this config for me:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 361.18  (buildd@lcy01-23)  Thu Jan 14 12:00:04 UTC 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nouveau"
#edit, i had to change ^ nvidia to nouveau in order for gui to start
    BusID          "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual     1920 1080
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Somehow it didn't get overwritten on boot.

What is causing the not-so-smooth experiences i have and how do i solve it?

*Graphics drivers, driver configuration, and things-that-might-prevent-me-from-booting-to-gui are not my strong points, so i'm only willing to try things that i can recover from if things go wrong.*

### What i know:

- Booting without the `nogpumanager` flag will restore my xorg.conf to defaults.
- Using nvidia driver instead of nouveau will prevent booting to the gui.

## Edit:

I tried to reproduce the problem¸but something else happened. With a coupl e of programs open, the gui froze on alt-tab and turned pitch black.
Any sounds from the programs did not stop, and i was able to access the TTYs.
I needed to restart lightdm to get back into the gui.

#### ~/.xsession-errors (the full output, only two lines):

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

#### /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old (from the black screen):

The part from `NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"` to `reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A...` is there because i switched from gui (tty7) to tty2.

```
[  1485.990] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1485.990] (II) intel(G0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1486.072] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  1486.128] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.137] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.144] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.148] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.159] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.168] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.176] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1486.182] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.369] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1523.370] (II) intel(G0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1523.460] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  1523.511] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.518] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.523] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.533] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.542] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.551] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.559] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1523.567] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.636] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1533.636] (II) intel(G0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1533.724] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  1533.775] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.782] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.791] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.797] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.807] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.815] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.821] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1533.830] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.439] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1592.440] (II) intel(G0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1592.520] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  1592.576] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.582] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.592] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.599] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.607] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.615] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.622] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1592.632] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1614.636] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1614.636] (II) intel(G0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1614.932] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[  1615.010] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.018] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.028] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.034] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.044] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.053] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.061] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1615.068] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7A62FE502E17CBF754B0622983D8729CAFBF8366.xkm
[  1625.398] (EE) 
[  1625.398] (EE) Backtrace:
[  1625.399] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x563c7bd7f5a6]
[  1625.399] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x563c7bbcc000+0x1b7709) [0x563c7bd83709]
[  1625.399] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7fa6e5f94000+0x352f0) [0x7fa6e5fc92f0]
[  1625.399] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fa6e1663000+0xb4d6e) [0x7fa6e1717d6e]
[  1625.399] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fa6e1663000+0x594ad) [0x7fa6e16bc4ad]
[  1625.399] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fa6e1663000+0x8d8ea) [0x7fa6e16f08ea]
[  1625.399] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fa6e1663000+0x5c3e16) [0x7fa6e1c26e16]
[  1625.399] (EE) 
[  1625.399] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x28
[  1625.399] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1625.399] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[  1625.399] (EE) 
[  1625.399] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1625.399] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1625.399] (EE) 
[  1625.399] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Sounds like X or your desktop environment is crashing. Anything in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`, or `~/.xsession-errors` (that last one would have to be from the CLI, before logging back in to the GUI, I'm afraid—you could just quickly `cp` it to somewhere from the CLI, then log in to the GUI and look at it from there.) In all those files, look from the bottom (end) for error messages.